# Create Reminder in vb.net (get message before 10 days from specified date)

Tags: vb.net, date, ms-access, reminders

I want to create a reminder based on a visa expiry date column in access database for each record to compare with.

What I want is to show a message 10 days before the visa expiry date of any record in my database, so that I know that this person his visa will be expired soon?

Comment: This is a bit broad.... what have you tried? Do you have a front end? Is it a web or windows form?

Comment: sorry for not clearing my idea, it's a windows form in vb.net and I am still not sure about how to do it.

Comment: You would need a function that is called on a regular basis or each time you open the application. This function would query your database and return a list of people where the Visa Expiry Date is less than 11 days from todays date. You could then display this list in a table or a pop up etc.

Comment: Please can you help me with the code of this function ?

Comment: I have helped... On SO we do not code answers... you have to do this yourself... We can help if you have some issues but we need to see your code.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I'm not look for full code just some hint that help !!